# How to hide Facebook followers list

Tags: facebook, followers

I want to hide the names of my followers on Facebook. This image shows what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: followers list hidden]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to your profile page
2. Click the *Friends* tab (under profile photo along *Timeline, About, Photos, Friends, More*)

   [image: edit privacy from friends page]
3. Click the pencil Edit icon
4. Select *Edit Privacy*

[image: edit privacy popup]

An *Edit Privacy* popup will appear with these options:

- Friend List
- Following
- Followers

Click on the dropdown arrow on the right of *Followers* and select "Only Me" or whatever you prefer.

Now the list of people who are following you will be restricted to the setting you've chosen.

Comment: But now nobody can see my followers number on my profile. That setting hide followers list and followers number, i want to hide just followers list.

Comment: Can you see followers of this boy: https://www.facebook.com/Vigheciu.Fcsb/followers

Comment: 9,117 Followers but no names. Just blank

Comment: How can i do that? How can i make followers names blank?

Comment: There are no names, or photos, just a blank page and at the top a number of followers

Comment: How can i hide my followers names like this : www.facebook.com/Vigheciu.Fcsb

Comment: How can i hide followers names :| Like this guy https://www.facebook.com/jrrarmando Can you see his followers? No, just count.

Comment: If i do like you in photo, will hide both, the number of followers and followers list too

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Facebook changed the way we can hide the list of people that follow us. In my case, I was trying to do this in order to protect their privacy (as well as mine, since I'm not fond of strangers knowing who are the people that probably know me).

The way I found (as of July 2021) is to go into "Settings and privacy" > "Privacy shortcuts" > "See more privacy settings" > "Public Posts", then set "Who Can Follow Me" to "Friends".

[image: Where to find the setting]

I tested with another profile (which is not a "friend" of my profile) and when this is set to public they can see my follower list, but as soon as I switch it to "Friends", the follower list is no longer visible (of course, I also hid my friends list but that was done long ago).

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible what you are trying to do, Facebook has changed thier rules.

https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=665931270100767